# Video recording mode screen does not fit mobile screen

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am using Dji sdk for a while no and I have a problem.
am using Huawei mate 20 pro, when I change the recording mode to video the screen does goes weird as show in the picture.

[image: video screen]

is there anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

By wired do you mean the big blank space?  To me it looks like aspect ratio issue.  Maybe the 20p has an off standard resolution configured?

Comment: looks like it, do u possibly know anyway to work around the issue?